# Pronouns direct and indirect

Tags: gramática, pronombres

> ¿El director les quiere dar el guión a los actores?
>
> Sí, quiere dárse**los**  or Sí, quiere dárse**lo**.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

Since you see:

> ¿El director les quiere dar **el guión** a los actores?

It only refers to a **singular noun**, so the answer would be :

> "Sí, quiere dárse**lo**.

Answer (score 2):

`Dar` is a transitive verb (dar *algo* a *alguien*), and the C.D. here is "el guión" (because if put in passive voice the sentence would be "El guión será dado a los actores por el director").

So, the pronoun in "dárselo/s" refer to "el guión". Since it is singular the appropriate would be "Sí,quiere dárse**lo**".

You would "darse**los**" if we were talking about giving several scripts ("guiones") to the actors. The concordance is with the direct object, not with the indirect.

> ¿Quiere el director dar **el guión** al actor? Sí, quiere dárse**lo**.
>
> ¿Quiere el director dar **el guión** a los actores? Sí, quiere dárse**lo**.
>
> ¿Quiere el director dar **los guiones** al representante? Sí, quiere dárse**los**.